# What exactly is different between "outspoken"/"softspoken" and "unspoken"/"misspoken"?

Tags: verbs, prefixes, past-participles

My brain completely misinterprets the last 2 of these words every time I read them:

- When I hear X is "unspoken", I interpret it to mean nobody speaks about X.
- When I hear X is "misspoken", I interpret it to mean that people say X by mistake.
- When I hear X is "outspoken", I interpret it as meaning that X is spoken of (or X does speaks) but the speech tends to be drowned out by others' voices.
- When I hear X is "softspoken", I interpret it as meaning that people tend to speak "softly" of X.

Yet somehow, it seems the first two are correct, but the last two are wrong.
Heck, the first two apply to things, whereas the last two seem to apply to *people*.
In the first two cases, X is the *subject* of the sentence, but in the last two, it is the *object*.

- Shouldn't the consistent usage and the "-en" conjugation mean X is the subject?
- From a language standpoint, what exactly is different about these that makes their meanings so seemingly ambiguous grammatically?

Comment: What does a dictionary say?

Comment: @HotLicks: It says "outspoken" means *frank in stating one's opinions*, and "softspoken" means *speaking or said with a gentle, quiet voice*. Your point?

Comment: @HotLicks: I have, and I was never asking for the definitions. Did you actually read the question?

Comment: "Can someone explain what is going on?" Certainly. "Language" is going on.

Comment: @Mick: *"Language" is going on.* ...well thank you for the insightful comment.

Comment: "Outspoken" means that Fred "speaks out" -- he makes his opinions heard, and will likely argue with anyone who disagrees.  "Soft-spoken", on the other hand, means that Joe is fairly quiet, and does not attempt to force his ideas and opinions onto others.  How are these not consistent with the words "out + spoken" and "soft + spoken"?

Comment: @HotLicks: Because by that logic "unspoken" would mean "does not speak" rather than "is not spoken of", and "misspoken" would mean "utters incorrectly" rather than "is uttered incorrectly". "Uneaten" would mean "does not eat" rather than "is not eaten", etc... again, did you read the question? I literally gave you 2 concrete examples to illustrate and contrast the difference.

Comment: Mehrdad - I can kind of understand your reasoning for outspoken. But the “out” in outspoken is not like the “out” in outbid or outdone. But as @HotLicks says, you need to simply read the definition and use it that way. Not all words use the same formulas for composition.

Comment: As Mick said, "language" is going on.  The words are not invented by some academic committee, but are developed by ordinary people going about their ordinary lives.

Comment: Which is to say that they're not regular because they don't have to be. For any regularity in language there is at least one exception; normally a large number.

Comment: @Jim: Well that's what I'm trying to do, but that's not answering my question. I'm asking for an explanation of some sort. Is it a different verb tense or grammar rule I might not know about? Has it always followed normal grammar rules, or was it used incorrectly and fall in use recently? Is it really as uncommon as it seems, or are there lots of other examples? There are *so many* more enlightening answers possible here other than "go read the dictionary"... I'm baffled why you guys keep trying to give me the definition and shut down the question when that's not something I even asked for.

Comment: **Everything** in English makes/made perfect sense to the person who first said/used it.  The trick is to understand what their context was and that way it will make sense to you too.  If something doesn’t make sense to you, then you must stop and ask yourself how should I be looking at this differently?  Your notice that the first two apply to things and the second two to people is right on.

Comment: @Jim: But *is* it right on? It's not actually a people vs. thing issue. If I say X is "uneaten" the meaning is the same whether it's referring to someone who just got attacked by a bear, or whether it's referring to a deer: it means nobody ate X. If I say X is "undriven", it means nobody drove X (X could either be a car, or a person to be motivated to do something). But if I say "unspoken" then suddenly there's a change in the subject. It has nothing to do with people or things. So that's why I'm asking -- I don't see the pattern. If I did then that would help.

Comment: Yes, it is. I didn’t say it was the complete and only reason for all *un-/out-” words. I said you were on the right track in starting to notice what makes these usages different.

Comment: @Jim: Hm, well, 2 data points don't really imply any kind of pattern, otherwise you could find a pattern between pretty much anything. Do you have 2-3 other consistent examples at least? I feel like these are the only two I can think of (maybe 1 more I might be forgetting, not sure), but otherwise I've been hard pressed to find anything I'd recognize as a pattern.

Comment: In the sentence "X is *prefix-*spoken", X is always the [subject](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/subject.htm). Why do you say that it is the object in your second pair of sentences?

Comment: I've edited your question extensively, following some of the discussion on the [related meta question](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/9893/142322) you raised. My intention was to clarify your question and address some of the issues raised, such as 'identify your main question'. If I've missed the mark, please feel free to edit further or to roll back the changes.

Comment: @Lawrence: Regarding your first comment (I've replied to the second one on Meta): If "X is *prefix*-spoken" really always has X as a subject, then what about the other examples I gave -- "X is unspoken"? X is clearly not a subject despite the "un-" prefix, right?

Comment: @Mehrdad In the sentence "X is Y.", X is *always* the subject (see the link in my comment above). I think what you're describing is something different - the change from typically-concept-X to typically-person-X.

Comment: @Lawrence: OH, I see what you mean now. Yes, you're right -- I guess X is the one doing "is", so it is technically the subject... which makes it hard because now I don't know what the proper term for this is. But what I mean is, "X is Y-en" normally means "Y occurs to X", whereas in these two particular cases it means "X makes Y occur (to some Z)". I don't know what the word for this is, but I think it should be pretty clear what I'm asking? Again, I don't see how it can depend on whether X is a person -- [see above](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/364022#comment847998_364022).

Comment: Off topic: has "he is outspoken" a negative connotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's involved here is a tension between transitive and intransitive uses of the past participle *spoken*.

Ordinarily a past participle employed as an adjective has a *passive* sense: the noun modified is the object of the verb, subject of the passive construction:

> John did not speak Mary's name, but everyone knew who he was talking about.
>   Mary's name was not spoken.
>   Mary's name was ***unspoken***.

Only the past participles of *transitive* verbs can be employed this way, because only transitive verbs have objects and only transitive verbs can be passivized.

Consequently, the past participles of ***in**transitive* verbs are rarely used as adjectives; but there's a handful which are, and in these cases the participle has an active and usually perfective sense.

- A *widely travelled* woman is not a woman who "has been travelled" widely, because *travel* is used transitively only of places, not of persons; she is a woman who ***has travelled*** widely.
- A *risen dough* is not a dough which "has been risen", because *rise* is intransitive (the transitive version is *raise*); it is a dough which ****has risen***.

*Speak* has both transitive and intransitive uses: one may *speak* a speech or a word AND one may simply "speak", loudly or softly or *out* or *of* a topic. And the compounds you adduce employ the participle in different senses:

- *Unspoken* is a passive use—the entity modified is *not spoken*.
- There's a verb *misspeak* which is almost always used intransitively—"When I said that I misspoke"—so in theory the participle would be employed as an active; but I've never actually seen *misspoken* employed as an adjectival in any sense, and I would be considerably more surprised to find it used actively than passively.
- *Outspoken* derives from *speak out*; this is usually intransitive, and in fact the adjective means "given to speaking out", often with the implication that what is said is injudicious or ill-considered.
- *Soft-spoken* derives from *speak soft(ly)*, intransitive, and means "given to speaking softly" rather than loudly or harshly.

Comment: Excellent analysis & explanation.

Comment: +1 FINALLY! After so much pain and tears battling to keep my question open, it's great to see this ray of light shining through. :) Thanks so much, this is *exactly* the kind of answer I was hoping for. I learned a lot from your answer, and the part where you point out that "outspoken" is derived from "speak out" (whereas "misspeak" isn't from "speak mis") seems to nail a crucial distinction I didn't notice (even though it seems so obvious in hindsight). I learned what a transitive verb is and I even learned a new word from your answer ("adduce")! Wish I could +100 this.

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm happy to have been of service. And don't let the difficulty you had with this question turn you against ELU--it is often very hard for native speakers to understand exactly what a learner's problem is, because the problems never arise for us :)

Comment: @StoneyB: It's funny because at this point nobody still considers me an English learner (at least, no more than anyone who only speaks English)... almost all of my education has been in native English schools, so by pretty much everyone's standards I'm considered a native speaker. It's only at odd times like this when I run into problems that truly native speakers never seem to, and then am reminded that English is my second language!

Comment: @Mehrdad I'm a 69-year-old native speaker, a professional writer, with a doctorate in LitCrit, and I'm still learning. This answer is something I learned this afternoon--because you asked and made me *think* about it. Thanks!

Comment: @StoneyB: Makes me happy to hear that :)

Answer (score 6):

All four describe the manner in which something is spoken:

- *unspoken* criticism
- *misspoken* criticism
- *outspoken* criticism
- *softspoken* criticism

The latter pair can further be used to describe individuals who habitually speak in the stipulated manner, as you've noticed: similarly, we have *plainspoken*, *free-spoken*, *well-spoken*, and *loud-spoken*, among others.

*Misspoken* and *unspoken* in contrast, are the past participles of the verbs *misspeak* and *unspeak*, respectively, and are not extensible, as with *forespoken* and *respoken*, among others. All of these verbs save the first are archaic/literary/obsolete today, however.

Comment: This is quite interesting! To make sure I am understanding it correctly: are you saying that the pattern/rule is the following? *When we say "X is Y-spoken", Y refers to X as the object if and only if 'Y-spoken' is itself a standalone verb; otherwise, Y refers to X as the subject.*

Answer (score 3):

I have been trying to work out the best way to answer this and although there are exceptions, these are the general patterns for the words you indicate that you have problems with.

**out—** words

- An **outspoken** person maybe *speaks out* about something they believe in
- An **outreach** worker maybe someone who **reaches out** to help.
- A movie **outtake** is a scene which a director **takes out** of the movie.

**soft—** words

These are descriptive words which are opposite to **hard-** words and...

- A **soft-spoken** person will have *speech which is soft* in comparison to a hard-spoken person.
- A **soft-coated** dog will have *fur which is soft* compared to a hard-coated dog
- A **soft-hearted** person will have a *temperament which is soft* compared to a hardhearted person
- A **soft-centred** sweet will have a *centre which is soft* compared to a hard-centred.

The only exception I can think of at this time is **soft-boiled** which refers to an egg which is boiled but the yolk is soft and runny compared to a hard-boiled egg which isn't soft and runny at all.

Comment: I really appreciate the attempt (+1 for that), but unfortunately this is focusing on the wrong thing. The confusing part isn't the first half of the word; it's the second half. And the focus is on the grammar and the verb tense, not the vocabulary per se. The question is why *"X is [verb]en"* seems to change meaning from *"X is [verb]ed by some Y"* to *"X [verb]s some Y"*. What exactly is it that is converting X from the object into the subject of the sentence? Grammatically it seems the conjugation implies it should always be the object, so that's the confusing part.

Comment: (I also edited the question just now to clarify.)

Answer (score 2):

[unspoken](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=unspoken) is a word from the late 14th century, likely derived from Dutch/German roots, while [outspoken](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=outspoken) is of Scottish origin, from around 1800.  Entirely different times and cultures produced the two words.

Comment: +1 but soft- seems to be Germanic as well? (there's no entry for soft-spoken so I'm not sure)

Comment: @Mehrdad - I didn't research "soft-spoken".  You're welcome to do so, however.

Comment: +1 Just because they share a suffix doesn't mean that they have similar constructions today, or that they did when the words were coined.

Answer (score 0):

These words describe *how* something is spoken, generally.

un - not in public, but in private.

miss - incorrectly.

out - without much thought.

soft - at a low volume.

They are all ways of speaking: privately, poorly, frequently, and gently.

I learned two things researching this: soft-spoken is always hyphenated, and if you don't know the answer, leave a comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! +1 for the hyphen (though Wiktionary [accepts the non-hyphenated version too](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/softspoken)). But outspoken and soft-spoken refer to people and not things, right? And outspoken means "speaking frankly" rather than "speaking without much thought", right...? (You can speak frankly with a lot of thought, or just lie without any thought...)

Comment: @Mehrdad I would agree with you.  The answer here regarding **out-** words is not quite correct as an outspoken person **can** be speaking frankly with a lot of thought

Comment: Not sure where the “without much thought” thing comes from.  That’s not how I view that prefix at all.

Comment: I would generally regard "out" to imply "loudly".

Comment: I would modify my entry under out- to be without much or any internal debate or regret. Those are the thoughts I had in mind, but I see how without thought means thoughtless. I think outspoken implies no filters, they say what's on their mind, even if it isn't a popular idea, but have (perhaps) thought very carefully about it. I don't think it ever means "loudly" even if those two have high correlation.